# Unit test basic factory that uses $window with Angular

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a basic third-party service and I'm trying to unit-test it. I can't get it to `throwError`.

**example**

```
angular.module('example')
   .factory('exampleFactory', ['$window', function($window) {
        if(typeof $window.examplePlugin === 'undefined') {
           throw new Error('plugin not available');
        } else {
          return $window.examplePlugin;
        }
   }]);
```

**Unit test**

```
describe('Factory', function() {
   var $window, exampleFactory;

   beforeEach(module('example'));

   beforeEach(function() {

      module(function($provide) {
          $provide.value('$window', {});
      });

      inject(function(_$window_, _exampleFactory_) {
         exampleFactory = _exampleFactory_;
         $window = _$window_;
      });
   });

   it('should exist', function() {
      $window.examplePlugin = {};
      expect($window.examplePlugin).toBeDefined();
   });

   it('should throw an error', function() {
      function fn() { delete $window.examplePlugin; }
      expect(fn).toThrowError();
   });
});
```

Comment: You don't test third-party services. Test your own code and mock the rest

Comment: With this, I'm just testing to make sure that the developer included the third-party plugin. Because I inject the 'examplePlugin' into my controllers.

Comment: That's hardly the point of a unit test. Sounds more like integration testing.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've shown, I can only think of this

```
describe('Factory', function() {
    var $window;

    beforeEach(module('example', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('$window', $window = {});
    });

    it('returns examplePlugin if it is set', function() {
        $window.examplePlugin = 'foo';
        inject(function(exampleFactory) {
            expect(exampleFactory).toBe($window.examplePlugin);
        });
    });

    it('throws an error if examplePlugin is not set', function() {
        // not entirely sure I have this wrapped correctly
        // but trial and error should get you there
        expect(function() {inject(function(exampleFactory) {})}).toThrow();
    });
});
```

The main thing is that you need to set the desired properties of `$window` before injecting your factory.

Comment: With the second test, I keep getting the error 'plugin not available' when I run the test. The `toThrow` is failling somehow...

Comment: @cusejuice I had a feeling that might be an issue. See update